# Counting Columns for VLOOKUPS using Python

Tags: python, excel, vlookup

I am practicing Python, for which i am VERY new at, and thought i'd apply it to a small irritation I have when doing VLOOKUPS in excel. The databases we have are massive, >15,000 lines long, and up to and over GG in columns, so I want an easy way to check the number the column is for the lookup, rather than highlight, which lags, or counting manually.

I've tried the following code, which works to a degree. It allows me to check the value of two different 3 column codes (excel max is XFD); but if I am comparing between column AA and XFD there's an error as there is no value at [2] for the start, no array there.

How can I exclude this or check whether it exists before I perform the for loop?

```
def get_character_distance2(start,end):
endList = list(end)
print(endList)

startList = list(start)
print(startList)

firstDistance = 0
secondDistance = 0
thirdDistance = 0

totalEnd = 0
totalStart = 0

for item in endList[0]:
    firstDistance += (ord(item.upper()) - ord(startList[0])) + 1

for item in endList[1]:
    secondDistance += ((ord(item.upper()) - ord(startList[1])) + 1) * 26

for item in endList[2]:
    thirdDistance += ((ord(item.upper()) - ord(startList[2])) + 1) * 676

totalStart += firstDistance + secondDistance + thirdDistance
print(firstDistance)
print(secondDistance)
print(thirdDistance)
print(totalStart)
```

for the result:

```
get_character_distance2('AAA','ZZZ')
```

Result (Fine):

```
['Z', 'Z', 'Z']
['A', 'A', 'A']
26
676
17576
18278
```

Different Check:

```
get_character_distance2('AA','ZZZ')
```

Bad Result:

```
['Z', 'Z', 'Z']
['A', 'A']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-185-c330b0ebbf1d> in <module>()
----> 1 get_character_distance2('AA','ZZZ')

<ipython-input-182-a080de45986e> in get_character_distance2(start, end)
 23 
 24     for item in endList[2]:
---> 25         thirdDistance += (ord(item.upper()) - ord(startList[2]))
 26         thirdDistance +=1
 27         thirdDistance *= 676

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I simply want the same as the first, it to add the values of the for loops provided there is actually a level to count against. If there is no array value, it can be assumed that the number there is 0.

Comment: Here, you assumed that `startList` is the same size as `endList` which is 3, since you have three `for` loops. And the example you have used doesn't have that condition

Comment: Indeed, how can I make it ignore it if there is no value? As there could be 3, 2, or 1, but all three require a different calculation depending on their location

Comment: search for `try` and `except` in python. Here is a simple [example](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp).

Comment: are you stuck?? Here is another hint... put the `try` block before the three `for` loops, and initialize the three distances with zeros.

Comment: I think that's likely to work if I can work out how to do. It works for some instances but not others, it's probably how I'm writing it so I'm trying out some options

Comment: Got a solution using what you suggested, probably not as elegant as it could be, but it works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the below solution with Anwarvic's advice on `try` and `except`.

```
def get_character_distance2(start,end):
startList = list(start)
print(startList)

endList = list(end)
print(endList)

firstDistance = 0
secondDistance = 0
thirdDistance = 0

totalEnd = 0
totalStart = 0

for item in endList[0]:
    firstDistance += (ord(item.upper()) - ord(startList[0])) + 1

try:
    for item in endList[1]:
        secondDistance += ((ord(item.upper()) - ord(startList[1])) + 1) * 26
except:
    try:
        for item in endList[1]:
            secondDistance += ((ord(item.upper()) - ord('A')) + 1) * 26
    except:
        secondDistance = 0

try:
    for item in endList[2]:
        thirdDistance += ((ord(item.upper()) - ord(startList[2])) + 1) * 676
except:
    try:
        for item in endList[2]:
            thirdDistance += ((ord(item.upper()) - ord('A')) + 1) * 676
    except:
        thirdDistance = 0

totalStart += firstDistance + secondDistance + thirdDistance
print(firstDistance)
print(secondDistance)
print(thirdDistance)
print(totalStart)
```

Thank you very much!